# Avoid clicking of full layout

Tags: java, android

I only want my textview with id `clickable_txtView` to be clickable in relative layout. Here is the code -

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:clickable="false">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120sp"
            android:layout_height="130sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/flower"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="120sp"
            android:text="Dont click me />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/clickable_txtView"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="140sp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Click me" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        @OnClick(R.id.clickable_txtView)
    public void txtViewClick() {
        //Some event
    }
```

Thr problem is I am able to click whole relative layout and some event happens after onclicking relative layout.
How do I avoid this and make it limited to text view only.

Comment: What happens exactly when you are clicking on relative layout?

Comment: txtViewClick() method is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textview has an attribute `android:paddingTop="140sp"` which basically wraps over the entire relative layout, because of which you are having the problem with onClick behaviour.

[image]

Use this RelativeLayout structure (provide ID to the "don't click me" textview, and place the "clickable textview" below it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="120sp"
        android:layout_height="130sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/do_not_click"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="120sp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Dont click me" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clickable_txtView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/do_not_click"
        android:text="Click me" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help. :)
Also, remove the paddingTop from the non-clickable textView. When using RelativeLayout, use above,below attribtues for layout positioning.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity where you are inflating this view try this:

first initialize your textview

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clickable_txtView);
```

then apply clickListner on it

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do your work here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try adding below line to your parent layout

```
android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="true"
```

like

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="true">
```